# Spring WebApplicationInitializer (ServletContainerInitializer, @HandlesTypes) with Embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat8, servlet-3.0, spring-web

I fail to understand why in the following minimal project my implementation of Spring's `WebApplicationInitializer` interface is found when running tests within Eclipse and IntelliJ, but not when using Maven (`mvn clean test`).

With Eclipse and IntellIJ I see `INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.example.pack.DummyInitializer@26d678a4]`

With `mvn clean test` I see `INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath`.

In the test I start an Embedded Tomcat:

```
String pathToWebXML = new File("src/main/webapp/").getAbsolutePath();
tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setBaseDir("embedded_tomcat");
tomcat.setPort(0);
tomcat.addWebapp("", pathToWebXML);
tomcat.start();
```

The `web.xml` references a `ServletContextListener` implementation which creates a new (and empty) `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`.

I uploaded the example project to GitHub: https://github.com/C-Otto/webapplicationinitializer

Comment: What version of java are you using in IntelliJ. Do you use java 8?I noticed that in the pom file you use java 8

Comment: @Periklis Yes, I use Java 8. Did you see any hint that I don't run Java 8? I'm confused about your question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just wanted to make sure that the java version you are using in IntelliJ is the same version that you have defined in pom.xml. Whenever, I have time I would download your application and I' ll give it a try

Comment: OK. As far as I know, IntellIJ automatically imports the Maven settings (including the Java version).

Comment: The design decision is related to Spring Boot, which I do not use. However, the referenced Tomcat issue is insightful. Based on https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52853#c19 do you see a way to make Tomcat find/scan/... correctly in the Maven case?

Comment: I just found out that setting `useSystemClassLoader` to `false` in Surefire's configuration solves this specific issue. However, I do not fully understand the consequences, and I'd appreciate an explanation of the issue at hand. Also see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/class-loading.html

Comment: Alternatively it helps to disable `useManfestOnlyJar`. Still, this is something I do not understand. I'll give the bounty to anyone who explains this, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=447790 :)

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, the classpath used by Maven Surefire (and Maven Failsafe) in the default setting is not scanned by Tomcat. Most classes are referenced using a `MANIFEST.MF` file inside a JAR file.

One option is to disable the `useSystemClassLoader` setting of the Maven plugins. However, this changes the details of the classloader, which may cause other problems.

As another option one could disable `useManifestOnlyJar`, which may cause problems on Windows machine.

In our project we decided to remove the initializer classes, and instead register whatever they were supposed to do manually. In a concrete example, as our implementation of `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` was not found, we now register the security filter manually inside the `contextInitialized` method:

```
String filterName = AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
servletContext.addFilter(filterName, new DelegatingFilterProxy(filterName)).addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), false, "/*");
```

Comment: Another option is to make Tomcat also include the jars that are referenced via the manifest file in the jar created by surefire. This can be done in context.xml setting the Jar Scanner attribute scanManifest to true

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Tomcat to include the jars that are referenced via the manifest file in the jar created by surefire. This can be done in `context.xml` setting the Jar Scanner attribute `scanManifest` to true. This is the default in newer versions of Tomcat as stated here: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59961.